# How am I supposed to carry enough darts for a long adventure?

Tags: equipment, encumbrance, pathfinder-2e-playtest

While building a character for the Pathfinder 2 (playtest) I came across an interesting conundrum. In order to carry Darts, I need some sort of container to carry them in when I'm not actively about to throw them. There's no item like a Quiver or Bandolier, and a Backpack takes a lot of actions to retrieve items from.  The best option seems to be Belt Pouches, but they can only hold four Darts (Light bulk items) apiece. Do I really need to wear lots of belt pouches to carry around "active" Darts, and then replenish them from my backpack between encounters?

Comment: [Rob Liefeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Liefeld) [approves.](https://nerdsonearth.com/2015/04/what-was-in-all-those-pouches-from-90s-comics/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could just have a bunch of Sheaths, which weigh nothing. There is no limit to this in the rules.

You could have a Satchel, which can hold up to 2 bulk (20 Light darts).

You could re-envision a satchel as a bandolier of darts because seriously, same thing.

You could make up a Quiver, it's a playtest, it can't have every piece of equipment you'd ever want in it.

And, of course, pick them back up after each combat.

Comment: +1 - a leather belt with a lot of dart sheaths = ammo bandolier in everything but a name. Reskinning items without mechanics change wins the day.